# Substituting in variable at earlier stage in equation

Tags: quadratics

I have a somewhat very basic question. I have the following equations. Eq1 is the first raw form and then further simplying it leads to Eq2

[image]

My question is.

- If I substitute k=0 in Eq1, I get 0 = -1
- If I substiute k=0 in Eq2, I am able to solve the quadratic equation in s.

How come this happens since Eq2 came from Eq1?

Again, probably a very silly question.

Comment: The original equation is what counts: $\;k\;$ cannot be zero as then  the left side vanishes, what would render the equation as false. Observe also that it **must be** $$s^2+6x+9=(s+3)^2\neq0\iff s\neq -3$$ otherwise you divide by zero...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue that you raised occurs frequently in Algebra.

One starts with Constraint-1.

Then one determines that if Constraint-1 is satisfied, then Constraint-2 must also be satisfied.

Then, you determine all of the ways that Constraint-2 can be satisfied, and you discover that there is a way of satisfying Constraint-2 without satisfying Constraint-1.

Some people refer to this as Constraint-2 having extraneous roots.

My wording is simply that the navigation between Constraint-1 and (the **derived**) Constraint-2 is often a **one way** implication.

That is, Constraint-1 $~\implies~$ Constraint-2, 
rather than Constraint-1 $~\iff~$ Constraint-2.

The classic example of this is

- Constraint-1 : $x = 2.$
- Constraint-2 : $x^2 = 4.$

So, when starting with Constraint-1, and deriving Constraint-2, and then determining all of the solutions to Constraint-2, these solutions are each merely *candidate solutions* to Constraint-1.  Each candidate solution must be manually checked against Constraint-1.

However, assuming that Constraint-2 has been derived from Constraint-1, you do know that no solution to Constraint-1 is possible **unless** it is one of the *candidate solutions* to Constraint-2.

Comment: Understood. In future, when do I know that I need to recheck my Eq2 solution with Eq1 to see if it is valid? In other words what operation did I perform between Eq1 and Eq2 such that it generated a new constraint ?

Comment: It takes years of advanced study/experience to distinguish, at-a-glance, which derivations are one-way versus two-way implications.  The easiest course is to always assume that each Constraint-2 solution must always be checked against Constraint-1.  Note that this issue also arises when constructing an $\epsilon,\delta$ proof of continuity.  One starts with Constraint-1, and then *derives* that a specific Constraint-2 association between $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ seems pertinent.  However, to be valid, you then have to manually verify that the Constraint-2 association satisfies Constraint-1.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a silly a question.

Remember that you can only multiply an equation by a function that does not vanish in the domain of definition of the original equation if you are looking for equivalent transformations.

When you set $k = 0$ in the second equation, you obtain the solution $s = -3$.

But this is an extraneous root, because you had to assume that $s\neq -3$ in order to multiply both sides by the denominator given by $s^{2} + 6s + 9$. So, in both cases, setting $k = 0$ leads to an equation that has no solution.

Please let me know if you still need further assistance.